# Time of the day or time period using the package siunitx

Tags: siunitx, datetime

I would like to display the time of the day like 18h30 or 18h30m with `siunitx`. Is there a proper way to display time and time intervals?

I have read some discussions on the [Mailing-List](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/time-intervals-in-siunitx), but it seems to be outdated.

My personal solution was defining the following command:

```
\newcommand{\hms}[3]{
% Stunden nur zeigen, wenn gesetzt
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
  {}
  {\SI{#1}{\hour}}
%
% Luecke nur, wenn Stunden und Minuten
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1} \OR \isempty{#2}}
  {}
  {\,\,}
%
% Minuten nur zeigen, wenn gesetzt
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}
  {}
  {\SI{#2}{\minute}}
% %
% Luecke nur, wenn Minuten und Sekunden
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2} \OR \isempty{#3}}
  {}
  {\,\,}
%
%Luecke nur, wenn Sekunden und Stunden aber nicht Minuten
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2} \AND \NOT \isempty{#3} \AND \NOT \isempty{#1}}
  {\,\,}
  {}
%
% Sekunden nur zeigen, wenn gesetzt
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}
  {}
  {\SI{#3}{\second}}
}
```

What is your opinion? How would you typeset times and time periods?

Comment: I've been asked about this a few times. It's an awkward one, as the format people want ('18 h 30 min', for example) is not really a useful way to express times in a scientific form. It's one value with two units, and you wonder if the 30 min is really that accurate. So at the moment this is an area where you do have to implement what you feel is best.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been asked about this a few times. It's an awkward one, as the format people want ('18 h 30 min', for example) is really not a single idea for expressing a time in scientific work. You'd normally want to express in one unit, so in either hours or minutes, but not both. That said, it's not too hard to construct a function `\hms` which works in a similar way to `\ang` (the multiple-unit argument applies to the later too!). This needs a code test as well as `\IfNoValueTF`, which is a little awkward for end users, but something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \hms { o > { \SplitArgument { 2 } { ; } } m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \IfNoValueF {#1}
        { \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1} }
      \siunitx_hms_output:nnn #2
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \siunitx_hms_output:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \IfNoValueF {#1}
      {
        \tl_if_blank:nF {#1}
          {
            \SI {#1} { \hour }
            \IfNoValueF {#2} { ~ }
          }
      }
    \IfNoValueF {#2}
      {
        \tl_if_blank:nF {#2}
          {
            \SI {#2} { \minute }
            \IfNoValueF {#3} { ~ }
          }
      }
    \IfNoValueF {#3}
      { \tl_if_blank:nF {#3} { \SI {#3} { \second } } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\hms{10}\\
\hms{;10}\\
\hms{;;10}\\
\hms{10;10}\\
\hms{10;;10}\\
\hms{10;10;10}\\
\end{document}
```

should do what you want. I've included an optional first argument for local set up in the usual `siunitx` way.

Comment: Thank you for this good macro. I am not very aware with explicite syntax, and I'd to have the possibility to write 8 h 30 for example. Is it possible to simply adjust your code ? Thank you. Maybe something like \hms*{8;30}.

Answer (score 1):

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\hms}{sm}{%
    \StrCut[1]{#2}{;}{\H}{\MS}%
    \StrCut[1]{\MS}{;}{\M}{\S}%
    \IfStrEq{\H}{}{}{\edef\H{\SI{\H}{\hour}}}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \IfStrEq{\M}{}{}{\edef\M{\num{\M}}}%
    }{%
        \IfStrEq{\M}{}{}{\edef\M{\SI{\M}{\minute}}}%
    }%
    \IfStrEq{\S}{}{}{\edef\S{\SI{\S}{\second}}}%
\IfStrEq{\H}{}{% Pas d'heure
    \IfStrEq{\M}{}{% Pas de minutes
            \IfStrEq{\S}{}{% Pas de secondes
                }{% avec secondes
                \S
            }%
        }{% avec minutes
            \IfStrEq{\S}{}{% Pas de secondes
                \H~\M
                }{% avec secondes
                \M~\S
            }%
        }%
    }{% avec heure
    \IfStrEq{\M}{}{% Pas de minutes
            \IfStrEq{\S}{}{% Pas de secondes
                \H
                }{% avec secondes
                \H~\S
            }%      
        }{% avec minutes
            \IfStrEq{\S}{}{% Pas de secondes
                \H~\M
                }{% avec secondes
                \H~\M~\S
            }%
        }%
    }%
}
```