# How to improve this table please?

Tags: tables

I tried a table that have alighn decimal commas, but this doesn't work. Thank you

Original code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, boldline}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{array, cellspace, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\footnotesize
\caption{\small Naměřené amplitudy metodou ($\pi $,$\pi/2$) pro jednotlivé koncentrace}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{V{4}c|c|c|c|c|cV{4}}
    \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
    \multicolumn{1}{V{4}cV{2.5}}{$T$ (MJD)} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}cV{2.5}}{\centering $\alpha $} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}cV{2.5}}{\centering $\delta $} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}cV{2.5}}{$B$} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}m{1.2cm}V{2.5}}{\centering $V$} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}m{1.2cm}V{4}}{$B-V$}\\

\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
8585,154194&    3h44m03,5s& 24$^\circ$14'37"&   12,193& 12,021& 0,172\\
8585,164329&    3h47m29,1s& 24$^\circ$06'21"&   2,780&  2,870&   -0,090\\
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, boldline}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{array, cellspace, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}


  \begin{table}[h!]
\footnotesize
\caption{\small Naměřené amplitudy metodou ($\pi $,$\pi/2$) pro jednotlivé koncentrace}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
@{}
S[table-format=4,6]|
S|
S|
S[table-format=2,3]|
S[table-format=2,3]|
S[table-format=1,3]
@{}
}
    \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
    \multicolumn{1}{2.5}{$T$ (MJD)} & \multicolumn{1}{2.5}{\centering $\alpha $} & \multicolumn{1}{2.5}{\centering $\delta $} & \multicolumn{1}{2.5}{$B$} & \multicolumn{1}{1.2cm}{\centering $V$} & \multicolumn{1}{1.2cm}{$B-V$}\\

\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
8585,154194&    3h44m03,5s& 24$^\circ$14'37"&   12,193& 12,021& 0,172\\
8585,164329&    3h47m29,1s& 24$^\circ$06'21"&   2,780&  2,870&   -0,090\\


\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}

    \end{tabular}
\label{tabt1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is not compilable. Please add a compilable code, otherwise we don't know what you have and what you want.

Comment: I editted my question

Comment: Have a look at `siunitx` with `S` column (pre-)type.

Comment: How is the `V` column type defined? And how did you modify the `c` column type so that it accepts an optional argument?

Comment: I looked at siunitx and I tried it in the secound code, but it is not compilable. I deleted the V column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an improvement, here is one.

- No need of complicated column types
- Get rid of unnecessary packages
- Use `siunitx` to align commas
- Remove all vertical lines, use `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` (by `booktabs`) for table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[locale=FR]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=4.6]ccS[table-format=2.3]S[table-format=2.3]S}
    \toprule
        {$T$ (MJD)} & $\alpha$ & $\delta$ & {$B$} & {$V$} & {$B-V$}\\
    \midrule
        8585,154194 & 3h44m03,5s & 24$^\circ$14'37" & 12,193 & 12,021 & 0,172\\
        8585,164329 & 3h47m29,1s & 24$^\circ$06'21" & 2,780 & 2,870 & -0,090\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It might make sense to use `siunitx` also for proper units (duh), viz. `\SI{3}{hours}` or `\SI{3456789045678}{\second}`, see also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/7sZRB_dT4RQ

Comment: @OlegLobachev Yes, I agree. However, that is what the OP has already written, I don't change what the OP writes intentionally. If the OP wants, he can do it himself.

Answer (score 1):

So, I basically combined [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38957/142180) [existing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484535/142180) answers to this and then undid all the hours-minutes and degree-minutes-seconds thing OP had for the sake of scientific consistency, yay.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[locale=FR]{siunitx}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38957/142180
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \hms { o > { \SplitArgument { 2 } { ; } } m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \IfNoValueF {#1}
        { \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1} }
      \siunitx_hms_output:nnn #2
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \siunitx_hms_output:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \IfNoValueF {#1}
      {
        \tl_if_blank:nF {#1}
          {
            \SI {#1} { \hour }
            \IfNoValueF {#2} { ~ }
          }
      }
    \IfNoValueF {#2}
      {
        \tl_if_blank:nF {#2}
          {
            \SI {#2} { \minute }
            \IfNoValueF {#3} { ~ }
          }
      }
    \IfNoValueF {#3}
      { \tl_if_blank:nF {#3} { \SI {#3} { \second } } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484535/142180
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=4.6]ccS[table-format=2.3]S[table-format=2.3]S}
    \toprule
        {$T$ (MJD)} & $\alpha$ & $\delta$ & {$B$} & {$V$} & {$B-V$}\\
    \midrule
        8585,154194 & \hms{3;44;03,5} & \ang{24}14'37" & 12,193 & 12,021 & 0,172\\
        8585,164329 & \hms{3;47;29,1} & \ang{24}06'21" & 2,780 & 2,870 & -0,090\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=4.6]S[table-format=5.1]S[table-format=2.5]S[table-format=2.3]S[table-format=2.3]S}
    \toprule
        {$T$ (MJD)} & {$\alpha$, sec} & {$\delta$} & {$B$} & {$V$} & {$B-V$}\\
    \midrule
        8585,154194 & 13443.5 & \ang{24.24361} & 12,193 & 12,021 & 0,172\\
        8585,164329 & 13649.1 & \ang{24.10583} & 2,780 & 2,870 & -0,090\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Seconds and decimal degrees}
    \label{tab:my_label2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: as in the previous answer with above macro]
[image: with seconds and degrees unrolled]